# Ubuntu 23.04 and Nvidia 530

Tags: nvidia, 23.04, additional-drivers

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 23.04. I noticed that the upgrade **uninstalled** my Nvidia 530 drivers, and left me with nouveau.

Nvidia 530 doesn't appear in Additional Drivers, and apparently is not in the 23.04 repos (yet).

So I installed Nvidia 525 (proprietary, tested) using Additional Drivers.

Anybody have any ideas when/if Nvidia 530 will appear in Additional Drivers?

Has anybody installed Nvidia 530 from their website at https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/ and had any problems?

Answer (score 0):

As of June 14, 2023 nvidia-driver-530 is available for 23.04 (Lunar Lobster).  I just loaded it, and am here looking for help getting it to work.  I think I recall needing an other package, but am not sure which on yet

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, on June 14, they released 535 at the Nvidia web site. Neither 530 or 535 appear in Additional Drivers app, the preferred place to install Nvidia drivers. If you're having trouble with 530, it's probably because you got yours from the web site.

Comment: Ubuntu has recently released Nvidia 535 for 23.04.  That seems to be working well for me.  I had initial problems with Nvidia 530.  So maybe 535 will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

Problem. `nvida-smi` does not work and `prime-select query` only shows "auto". Ubuntu 23.04 nvidia 530. Sucks!

Comment: What version Nvidia, Ubuntu? Did you install it from Additional Drivers, or from a download at the Nvidia web site?

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/530-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-23-04/256721

Comment: From bash shell.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers devices` only show 530 being the latest. Not 535.